# Updating only non-null rows

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite, sql-update

I'm pretty new to SQL and I was wondering if I can update a column using a condition.

I have two columns, and I want to update the second one (B) only if there is something in the first one (A) :

```
'UPDATE Table1 SET ColumnB = (SELECT BG FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.ColumnC = BG.ColumnZ)'
```

How can I avoid to apply the update to the rows where column A is null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `EXISTS`, if you only want to update where there is a match:

```
UPDATE Table1 
    SET ColumnB = (SELECT BG FROM Table2 t2 WHERE table1.ColumnC = t2.ColumnZ)
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT BG FROM Table2 t2 WHERE table1.ColumnC = t2.ColumnZ );
```

If you want to update only where the first table has a non-`NULL` value, then use `WHERE` in the outer query:

```
UPDATE Table1 
    SET ColumnB = (SELECT BG FROM Table2 t2 WHERE table1.ColumnC = t2.ColumnZ)
    WHERE ColumnB IS NOT NULL;
```